# What is the equivalent of Java's Stream#Peek method in Linq C#?

Tags: java, c#, linq, java-8, java-stream

I have been used to using Java's **[`Stream#Peek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-)** method so much as it's a useful method to debug intermediate stream operation. For those of you who are not familiar with the **[`Stream#Peek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-)** method, below shows the definition of it:

> [**`Stream<T> peek(Consumer<? super T> action)`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-)
>
> Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream,
>   additionally performing the provided action on each element as
>   elements are consumed from the resulting stream. This is an
>   intermediate operation.

Consider this simple example below:

```
List<Integer> integerList = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
List<Integer> result = integerList.stream()
                                  .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
                                  .peek(System.out::println)
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

With the **[`Stream#Peek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-)** method, this should basically allow me to print all the even numbers to the console so that I can test to see if that's what I would expect.

I have tried to find an answer to the question at hand but can't seem to find a similar method in `C#`, does anyone know the equivalent of Java's **[`Stream#Peek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-)** or some other method with similar behavior?

Comment: There is ForEach method on List class (there is some debate on why it is not available for IEnumerable), so you would need to call "ToList" before using it. Although it returns void, not another list. But it is trivial to write your own extension method for IEnumerable which does that.

Comment: @user1242967 There's not *debate* on why it doesn't exist for `IEnumerable`.  There's debate as to whether or not it would be a good idea for `IEnumerable`, but why it doesn't has been clearly laid out and isn't in question.

Comment: @Servy Yeah, bad wording on my part.

Comment: @user1242967 I know about the `ToList()` extension method but that's not quite what `Stream#Peek` does. though if there's no other way to replicate the `Stream#peek` then your suggestion of writing my own extension method would be an option.

Comment: @Aominè Just to be clear, this is what I suggested: `ToList().ForEach(Console.Write)`

Comment: `"With the Stream#Peek method, this should basically allow me to print all the even numbers to the console so that I can test to see if that's what I would expect."` This statement is incorrect. In your example, `peek` will only print the result of `findFirst`. Kinda counter-intuitive if you ask me, but I guess that's the expected behavior.

Comment: @budi My bad, will edit the post to accommodate that statement. but yes due to `findFirst` being a short circuiting terminal operation what I said before was not correct. I have edited the post to illustrate my initial intention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no equivalent of `Peek` in LINQ - i.e. there is no method which performs some action *and* returns source elements. There is a `ForEach` method in `List` class which performs an operation on each element, but it does not return source elements, and as already said, it's not an `IEnumerable` extension.

But you can easily write your own extension

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Peek<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));

    return Iterator();

    IEnumerable<T> Iterator() // C# 7 Local Function
    {
       foreach(var item in source)
       {
           action(item);
           yield return item;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think declaring a local function just to execute it and return the results is redundant.  You would get the same effect with less code with just the foreach block.

Comment: @MattJohnson and how parameters check would work with deferred execution?

Comment: Deferred execution is achieved via use of `yield return` - not by calling a function.  You still get deferred execution both as currently written, and if you inline the function.  (Note you're not returning the function at all, you're just executing it.)

Comment: @MattJohnson question was about parameters check. I'll refine the question - when parameters check will occur with deferred execution?

Comment: It will occur when the enumerable that uses this function first begins enumeration, such as when a `.ToList()` or `foreach` is called on it.  It does this the same way, regardless of whether you have the local function or not.

Comment: Wait - no, I'm wrong... with the local function, the parameter checks occur ahead of time.  Without it it happens at time of enumeration... You were right, and I learned something! :)

Comment: @MattJohnson yep, that's the way LINQ methods implemented in the framework, but of course no local functions there - only private methods for each iterator

Answer (score 6):

You can use a `Select` with a [Statement Lambda](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions#statement-lambdas) for this.  Consider:

```
var integerList = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
var result = integerList
    .Where(i => i % 2 == 0)

    // this select uses a statement lambda
    .Select(i =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        return i;
    })

    .Whatever(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: this answer is outdated, after edits to the original question. The initial question was worded with the intention of `peek`-ing all the `filter`-ed values, then performing `findFirst`:

```
List<Integer> integerList = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
Optional<Integer> result = integerList.stream()
                                      .filter(i -> i % 2 ==0== 0)
                                      .peek(System.out::println)
                                      .findFirst();
```

---

As far as I know, there's no built-in LINQ solution to do this, so here's an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Peek<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            action(iterator.Current);
        }
    }

    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return iterator.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
var integerList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
int? result = integerList.Where(i => i % 2 == 0)
                         .Peek(i => Console.WriteLine(i))
                         .FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output:

```
2
4
6
8
10
2
```